# Why protocol must be sent to the socket function in big-endiannes order and the rest of the parameters not?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, endianness, ethernet

I was using the socket method of the socket lib in python which looks like this:

```
socket.socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None)
```

Now I have seen some means of using the method in order to filter ethernet packets, which looks like this:

```
import socket
ETH_P_ALL = 3
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
s.close()
```

I want to know where in the documentation it says that the proto parameter must be used in network endiannes ( big ).
And why just the proto parameter and also not the rest of them.
Why not this:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.htons(socket.AF_PACKET), socket.htons(socket.SOCK_RAW), socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know where in the documentation it says that the proto parameter must be used in network endiannes ( big )

From [man 7 packet](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html):

> ```
> packet_socket = socket(AF_PACKET, int socket_type, int protocol);
> ```
>
> ... protocol is the IEEE
>          802.3 protocol number **in network byte order**.  See the
>           include file for a list of allowed protocols.
>          When protocol is set to htons(ETH_P_ALL), then all protocols are
>          received.

Comment: Thank you ! Looked it up for a while without luck. U brightened my day.But how did you find this piece of info ?

Comment: @LonelyDagger: First hit I get when [searching for `ETH_P_ALL`](https://www.google.com/search?q=eth_p_all) is the documentation for packet(7) I've linked to.